# Can you create and send an IRM email with EWS 2010?

Tags: exchangewebservices

Have a need to programmatically create and send an IRM'ed email and don't want to do it via the Outlook API. Was hoping EWS 2010 had this functionality, but I didn't see it in the MSDN docs.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Thanx,

Dave